# Can't select or delete 3D contours - ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I used the "Create Contour" icon in 3D Analyst on a TIN. But now I can't hide, select, or delete those contours. I even tried deleting the base TIN to no avail.

ArcScene 10.0.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a 3D Analyst license to test this but I just looked up the help and found that **[Create Contours](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q80000008z000000)** creates a 3D polyline graphic.

Instructions for selecting graphics in ArcScene are **[here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q80000004w000000)**.

> You cannot use the interactive selection tools to select nonfeatures,
>   such as graphics, LAS points, or triangles, within a TIN surface. If
>   you have graphics added to your scene, you must use the Select
>   Graphics tool Select Graphics on the 3D Graphics toolbar (also
>   available on the Tools toolbar). Click the graphic element you want
>   selected. Holding SHIFT will add multiple elements to the current
>   selection, just as it does for feature selection.

You should then be able to use the `Delete` key.